# how to use slide.pageNumber() slides methods from pptxgenjs library

Tags: qlikview, pptxgenjs

I am using PPTxgenjs library. I want to show page number/slide number with my title like this `[Dashboard Reporting (Page 1...)]` on each slide. I tried Slide methods.

```
var pptx = null;
pptx=new PptxGenJS();
var slide=pptx.addNewSlide();
var slideNum=slide.pageNumber();
```

but it's giving me error

> slide.pageNumber() is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
var slide=pptx.addNewSlide();
slide1.slideNumber({ x:'50%', y:'95%', color:'0088CC' });
```

where `x` and `y` are slide1's position.
You can set it with your title position.